# What sections of ELF file are counted toward RSS for the program?

Tags: linux, memory, elf

I start to wonder what sections in ELF are counted to RSS (resident set size) for the program? If I have a lot of static strings (.rodata). Is it in RSS or not? And .text? Is it in RSS?

Comment: To me, RSS is a method  of syndicating updates. What are you using it to mean here?

Comment: @BarryCarter: Presumably `Resident Set Size`.

Answer (score 0):

None of the sections counts towards RSS. RSS is determined by the actual use of physical RAM. Both `.rodata` and `.text` can be swapped out, removing both from RAM and thus from RSS.

On the other hand, if there is enough RAM, and your program is run in a way that exercises all its code and all its data, then your entire `.rodata` and `.text` could in theory end up in RSS.

The "your program is run in a way that exercises all its code" restriction is because your program could well include a `--version` command-line option. This would probably not cause your entire `.text` to be loaded into RAM. Yet at the same time, if you **don't** pass `--version`, then the small bit of code responsible for that output won't run.

Comment: It sounds odd, because we have dynamic linkers and code in the ELF file is not the same as in RAM after linling, because of relocation tables.

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin: So?  That still can be swapped.

Comment: If it can be swapped as normal written memory with data, it should be counted toward RSS. If it can be 'thrown out' and read back from original binary ELF, then I do not understand what restore pointers from relocation table at that moment. Kernel is not providing those services...

Comment: @GeorgeShuklin: If it can be swapped out, **but is actually lives in RAM**, then yes it counts towards RSS.  Relocations happen by `ld.so`, no need to do this in the kernel.